# resharper export todo list

Tags: c#, resharper

I have resharper installed and I use the todo list functionality pretty often.
My question is, apart from doing a screenshot of the list is there a way to export the current list and so I can email it or communicate it to developers. Am not using team system and so cannot propogate changes/todo etc to other developers that way.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my version (3.1 C# edition) there is an Export button in the To-do Explorer. You might consider upgrading if you are using an older one, your key for 3.0 should work for this one as well.